# Access Bison variables to c++ project in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, bison

I am parsing a text file using bison which creates a c file. And I am initializing some variables in the bison file  from the information given in the text file. I want to use those variables in my c++ project in eclipse but how to access those initialized variables?

How to define an extern variable in the bison file?

Comment: If you just want a global variable, define it in the prologue (in between the `%{` and `%}`. Make sure you insert an `extern` declaration in the compilation unit in which you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

([Answered in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

@rici wrote:

> If you just want a global variable, define it in the prologue (in between the `%{` and `%}`. Make sure you insert an `extern` declaration in the compilation unit in which you want to use it.